# Jquery / JavaScript get value from a td of table which is inside a div with id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div id="myDiv">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Firstname
            </td>
            <td>
                Secondname
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                name1
            </td>
            <td>
                name2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

This is my HTML structure and I need to get the values **'Firstname'** and **'name1'** from the table using Jquery or Javascript. Only the outer div has the id. Can someone help.

Comment: I think the goal of this question is how to generate jquery selector. for this, you may add more classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, it's too easy.

```
jQuery('#myDiv table tr:first-child td:first-child').html() // 'Firstname'
jQuery('#myDiv table tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child').html() // 'name1'

jQuery('#myDiv table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2)').html() // 'Secondname'
jQuery('#myDiv table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').html() // 'name2'
```

Comment: my sample code is getting from first tr. I think they can get second tr values in same way.

Comment: Thanks @TomaszBucko, It's worked now. Perfect one using Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Firstname
            </td>
            <td>
                Secondname
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                name1
            </td>
            <td>
                name2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    const allTableRows = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv table tr');
    const firstRow = allTableRows[0];
    const secondRow = allTableRows[1];
    const firstNameLabel = firstRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
    const firstNameValue = secondRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;

    console.log(firstNameLabel.trim());
    console.log(firstNameValue.trim());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution using Javascript. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

hi try this i used class name here

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">
                Firstname
            </td>
            <td>
                Secondname
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="name">
                name1
            </td>
            <td>
                name2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and jquery here

```js
alert($('#myDiv td.first, td.name').text());
```

and here is 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/e9Lk5aph/3/)

Comment: Nikz says "Only the outer div has the id." so no classes inside